# Behaviour of `prepend` in Ruby class hierarchies

Tags: ruby, inheritance, decorator

I have a class `Base`, and two classes `Derived` and `Derived2` that inherit from `Base`. They each have a function `foo` defined in them.

I also have a module `Gen` which is `prepend`-ed to `Base`. It is also `prepend`-ed to `Derived2` but not to `Derived`.

When I call `foo` on an instance of `Derived2`, the result is as if the `Gen` module was only `prepend`-ed to `Base` and not to `Derived2` also. Is this the expected behavior?

Here is the code for the above scenario:

```
module Gen
  def foo
    val = super
    '[' + val + ']'
  end
end

class Base
  prepend Gen

  def foo
    "from Base"
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  def foo
    val = super
    val + "from Derived"
  end
end

class Derived2 < Base
  prepend Gen
  def foo
    val = super
    val + "from Derived"
  end
end

Base.new.foo     # => "[from Base]"

Derived.new.foo  # => "[from Base]from Derived"

Derived2.new.foo # => "[from Base]from Derived"
```

I expected the last of the above statement to output:

```
[[from Base]from Derived]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help you understand, there is a method `Class#ancestors`, which tells you the order in which a method will be searched for. In this case:

```
Base.ancestors     # => [Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Derived.ancestors  # => [Derived, Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Derived2.ancestors # => [Gen, Derived2, Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So when you call a method on an object that is an instance of said class, that method will be searched in the corresponding list in that order.

- Prepending puts a module in front of that list.
- Inheriting puts the parent's chain at the end of the child's (not exactly, but for simplicity's sake).
- `super` just says *"go traverse the chain further and find me the same method"*.

---

For `Base`, we have two implementations of `foo` - that in `Base` and that in `Gen`. The `Gen` one will be found first as the module was prepended. Therefore calling it on an instance of `Base` will call `Gen#foo` *=`[S]`*, which will search up the chain as well (via `super`) *=`[from Base]`*.

For `Derived`, the module wasn't prepended, and we have inheritance. Therefore, the first found implementation is that in `Derived` *=`Sfrom Derived`* and `super` will search the rest of the chain that comes from `Base` (aka the above paragraph is played out) *=`[from Base]from Derived`*.

For `Derived2`, the module is prepended, so the method there will be found first *=`[S]`*. Then the `super` there will find the next `foo` in `Derived2` *=`[Sfrom Derived]`*, and the `super` there will play out the situation for `Base` again *=`[[from Base]from Derived]`*.

---

**EDIT:** It seems that up until very recently, `prepend` would first search in the ancestors chain and add the module only if it is not already present (similarly to `include`). To make it even more confusing, if you first create the parent, inherit from it, prepend in the child and then prepend in the parent, you will get the result of newer versions.

Comment: I know how `prepend` is supposed to work. But the ancestors chain did not turn out to be what you printed above.

    1. `Base.ancestors  # => [Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`
    2. `Derived.ancestors # => [Derived, Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`
    3. `Derived2.ancestors # => [Derived2, Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

I am on Ruby 2.2.4.

Comment: Would you know which version this change of behavior was effected in?

Comment: @CppNoob I'll download 2.2.5 now, but it seems to have changed after 2.3+. It is not reflected in the documentation and I couldn't find it in the changelog either. It seems to be a regression, I will do some more investigation and report it.

Comment: @CppNoob, yes - it's 2.3.0

Comment: @CppNoob, this has been the "normal" behaviour up until 2.3.0. The `[Gen, Derived2, Gen, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` version comes with 2.3.0 that is. The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features) explicitly states that it shouldn't be prepended if it is already present in the chain. So it seems to be regression, I created [a ticket](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12834).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested you can achieve something like this for inheritance, basically for every subclass that inherits from `Base` add Gen to its ancestors :

```rb
class Base
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.prepend(Gen)
  end

  def foo
    "from Base"
  end
end
```